# NVIDIA RTX 2080 Ti with Ubuntu 18.04: poor performance

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-18.04

I installed drivers nvidia-410 on Ubuntu 18.04 for new NVIDIA RTX 2080 Ti. However, graphic card shows poor performance. glmark2 gives the score 3458 ([glmark2 results screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvwTN.png)) and TensorFlow-gpu (running in docker container) is much slower than it should be.

Reinstalling drivers to 430 didn't help. I would appreciate any help to fix it!

Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9600K CPU @ 3.70GHz

[nvidia-settings/GPU-0 info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UAXgK.png)

[nvidia-smi screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GmqCJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

I also have reduced performance on Ubuntu 18.04 with

1. AMD Ryzen 2700X
2. NVidia RTX 2080
3. 16GB 2400MHz RAM,

but performance is still satisfactory with CUDA 10.1. I am benchmarking with MXNet.

What is your PC's RAM? Maybe it is throttling performance?

I will try to update answer on Monday, hopefully I will be at work.